# Join 2 tables where right date is greatest date less than or equal to left date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, join, outer-join

I have 2 tables I'd like to join in Oracle SQL:

```
Table A:
DATE        VALUE
02-May-19   19.25
03-May-19   19.35
04-May-19   19.37
06-May-19   19.45
11-May-19   19.30
01-Jun-19   18.79
01-Jul-19   19.33

Table B:
DATE        VALUE
02-May-19   11.08
01-Jun-19   11.09
01-Jul-19   11.11
```

I can left outer join them to bring in both values where the dates match:

```
select a."date" as "DATE", a.value as a_value, b.value as b_value
from a 
left outer join b on b."date" = a."date"
;

DATE        A_VALUE B_VALUE
02-May-19   19.25   11.08
03-May-19   19.35   
04-May-19   19.37   
06-May-19   19.45   
11-May-19   19.30   
01-Jun-19   18.79   11.09
01-Jul-19   19.33   11.11
```

What I'd like to be able to do is where the date doesn't exist in table B take the best available b.value where b."date" <= a."date". Like so:

```
DATE        A_VALUE B_VALUE
02-May-19   19.25   11.08
03-May-19   19.35   11.08
04-May-19   19.37   11.08
06-May-19   19.45   11.08
11-May-19   19.30   11.08
01-Jun-19   18.79   11.09
01-Jul-19   19.33   11.11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query you could add lag function with ignore nulls option:

```
select a."date"
     , a."value"
     , coalesce(b."value", lag(b."value") ignore nulls over (order by a."date")) as best_match_value
from a 
left outer join b on b."date" = a."date"
order by a."date";
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest method is a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select max(b.value) keep (dense_rank first order by b.date desc)
        from b
        where b.date <= a.date
       ) b_value
from a;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `month()` and `year()` function in join condition

```
select a.date, a.value, b.value 
from a 
left outer join b 
on EXTRACT(month FROM b.date)=EXTRACT(month FROM a.date) 
and EXTRACT(year FROM b.date)=EXTRACT(yearFROM a.date)
```

Comment: `month` and `year` function ... in Oracle ??

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, thank u - I didn't notice the db tag